# my data cleaning script is slow, any ideas on how to improve?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-cleaning

I have a Data(csv format) where the first column is an epoch timestamp(strictly increasing) and the other columns are cumulative rows(just increasing or equal).
Sample is as below:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame([[1515288240, 100, 50, 90, 70],[1515288241, 101, 60, 95, 75],[1515288242, 110, 70, 100, 80],[1515288239, 110, 70, 110, 85],[1515288241, 110, 75, 110, 85],[1515288243,110,70,110,85]],columns =['UNIX_TS','A','B','C','D'])
df =
id    UNIX_TS  A   B   C  D
 0 1515288240 100 50  90 70
 1 1515288241 101 60  95 75
 2 1515288242 110 70 100 80
 3 1515288239 110 70 110 85
 4 1515288241 110 75 110 85
 5 1515288243 110 70 110 85

import pandas as pd
def clean(df,column_name,equl):
    i=0
    while(df.shape[0]-2>=i):
        if df[column_name].iloc[i]>df[column_name].iloc[i+1]:
            df.drop(df[column_name].iloc[[i+1]].index,inplace=True)
            continue
        elif df[column_name].iloc[i]==df[column_name].iloc[i+1] and equl==1:
            df.drop(df[column_name].iloc[[i+1]].index,inplace=True)
            continue
        i+=1

clean(df,'UNIX_TS',1)
for col in df.columns[1:]:
    clean(df,col,0)

df =
    id    UNIX_TS  A   B   C  D
     0 1515288240 100 50  90 70
     1 1515288241 101 60  95 75
     2 1515288242 110 70 100 80
```

My script works as intended but its too slow, anybody has ideas about how to improve its speed.

I wrote a script to remove all the invalid data based on 2 rules:

1. Unix_TS must be strictly increasing(because its a time, it cannot flow back or  pause),
2. other columns are increasing and can be constant for example is in one row it is 100 and the next row it can be >=100 but not less.

Based on the rules the index 3 & 4 are invalid because unix_ts 1515288239 is 1515288241 are less than the index 2.
index 5 is wrong because the value B decreased

Comment: explain the part where the cleaning should happen and what is the cleaning part?

Comment: I added the rules to clean the data, Is it understandable?

Comment: okay .. but the example data doesnot faulty data. :)

Comment: it has a fault, right? look at index 3, it is less than index 2 and index 4 is less than index 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, can use

```
cols = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
mask_1 = df['UNIX_TS'] > df['UNIX_TS'].cummax().shift().fillna(0)
mask_2 = mask_2 = (df[cols] >= df[cols].cummax().shift().fillna(0)).all(1)

df[mask_1 & mask_2]
```

Outputs

```
    UNIX_TS     A   B   C   D
0   1515288240  100 50  90  70
1   1515288241  101 60  95  75
2   1515288242  110 70  100 80
```

Comment: Hi, the solution is not right because in mask_1 it should identify row index 3 and 4 as false. But your's only say index 3 as false but not index 4.

Comment: @BhanuTez it *does* identify index3 and 4 as False. You have to look at the result of `mask_1 & mask_2`

Comment: Ya.. only because of column B, what if column B has good data? I will add extra data in the example, so others can understand easily.